# How did I reverse my Excel Datasheet Display?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

How did I reverse the layout of my workbook?

I was about to paste some data by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and now Cell A1 is in the top right of my worksheet instead of the top left.  Everything in the datasheet is oriented the other way.  The ribbon and other toolbars are oriented the original way.  Old workbooks are normal. New workbooks are now reversed.

I checked my list of keyboard shortcuts but didn't see an entry for reversing the datasheet layout. Obviously I pressed one or more extra keys.  I can not re-create the behavior.

Does anyone know the key combination to do this on purpose?

[image: reversed worksheet]

Version: Excel 2013 (15.0 64-bit)

Comment: You might have changed the Excel writing direction from l-to-r into r-to-l (as is usual for example for many arabic countries). The text in each field is still formatted l-to-r. However, I don't know a key sequence for that.

Comment: I think it's at ribbon - layout - sheet options - sheet right to left, but I don't have 2013 (or 2010, etc) and can't check for shortcuts. Something like alt-P-??

Comment: @aganju, Good catch.  Under Options> Advanced> Display, the default direction was changed to Right-to-left.  Clicking the Left-to-Right corrected the problem.  Thanks.  But what's the keyboard combination to do this?

Comment: @B540Glenn I think you'll only see the option in Page Layout | Sheet Options if you have installed language support for a Right-to-Left language. While I don't think Excel has a hotkey to toggle this, perhaps it toggles if you change languages. So if you have installed language support for a RTL language, perhaps you accidently pressed the hotkey to toggle the language (Left-ALT + SHIFT, or CTRL+SPACE, etc. ... see Advanced Key Settings of your Language bar Settings for your shortcuts).

Comment: @DeltaHotel, I'll check for some sort of language activity.  While I normally don't have the language bar active, it doesn't mean the network admins haven't been quietly changing things. Thanks for the suggestions.